# How to execute gcloud build trigger using curl in us-central1 region?

Tags: gcloud

In **Google Cloud Build** I select **Triggers** -> **Create Trigger**. For region I use **us-central1**. Event: **Webhook Event**.

Webhook URL preview shows me the following url:

```
https://cloudbuild.googleapis.com/v1/projects/PROJECT_ID/triggers/TRIGGER_NAME?key=XXXXXXXX&secret=XXXXXXXX
```

When I try to `curl` it I got:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 404,
    "message": "triggerError spanner trigger (11111111111, TRIGGER_NAME) not found",
    "status": "NOT_FOUND"
  }
}
```

This only happens when I create trigger in **us-central1** region. Triggers created in **global** region works fine.

How should I tell `cloudbuild.googleapis.com` to look for a trigger from region **us-central1**?

--- Update ---

This is the way I execute webhooks:

```bash
$ curl https://cloudbuild.googleapis.com/v1/projects/{PROJECT}/triggers/hello-central1:webhook \
    -d key=xxx \
    -d secret=xxx
# {
#   "error": {
#     "code": 404,
#     "message": "triggerError spanner trigger (11111111111, hello-central1) not found",
#     "status": "NOT_FOUND"
#   }
# }

$ curl https://cloudbuild.googleapis.com/v1/projects/{PROJECT}/locations/us-central1/triggers/hello-central1:webhook \
    -d key=xxx \
    -d secret=xxx
# {
#   "error": {
#     "code": 400,
#     "message": "Request contains an invalid argument.",
#     "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
#   }
# }

$ curl https://cloudbuild.googleapis.com/v1/projects/{PROJECT}/triggers/{TRIGGER}:webhook \
    -d name=projects/{PROJECT}/locations/us-central1/triggers/{TRIGGER} \
    -d key=xxx \
    -d secret=xxx
# {
#   "error": {
#     "code": 400,
#     "message": "Request contains an invalid argument.",
#     "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
#   }
# }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the way to execute trigger from region different from global:

```
curl https://cloudbuild.googleapis.com/v1/projects/$PROJECT/locations/$REGION/triggers/$TRIGGER:webhook \
    -d key=$KEY \
    -d secret=$SECRET \
    -d trigger=$TRIGGER \
    -d projectId=$PROJECT
```

Another way:

```
curl "https://cloudbuild.googleapis.com/v1/projects/$PROJECT/locations/$REGION/triggers/$TRIGGER:webhook?key=$KEY&secret=$SECRET&trigger=$TRIGGER&projectId=$PROJECT" -d {}
```

Yet another way:

```
curl -X POST -H Content-Type:application/json "https://cloudbuild.googleapis.com/v1/projects/$PROJECT/locations/$REGION/triggers/$TRIGGER:webhook?key=$KEY&secret=$SECRET&trigger=$TRIGGER&projectId=$PROJECT"
```